# numbers instead of date in my python plot

Tags: python, date, plot, charts, finance

I tried to plot stock price but I had a little issue: my dates are wrong on my chart.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
# Set the start and end date
start_date = '1990-01-01'
end_date = '2019-02-01'
# Set the ticker
ticker = 'AAPL'
# Get the data
data = data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start_date, end_date)
data.head()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data['Adj Close'].plot()
plt.show()
```

Instead of a date I get : 3960, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matplotlib` [`num2date`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.num2date) to do the conversion.

```
from matplotlib.dates import num2date

plt.plot(num2date(data['date']), data['Adj Close'])

plt.show()
```

You'll need to pass `num2date` whatever column it is that has the dates in it, I've used `'dates'` as an example.

In fact, just calling `plot` from `matplotlib` instead of from `pandas` (because you are calling it from a dataframe) may do the trick without `num2date`.

Comment: I ve tried but I got an error : The epoch2num function was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  base = dates.epoch2num(dt.asi8 / 1.0e9)

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the date strings

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime.strptime('1990-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
end_date = datetime.strptime('2019-02-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```